# Ширина абсолютно позиционированного элемента по его содержимому

Tags: css, html5, css3

Есть такого рода код (ниже привел), в нем я модной зеленой `dotted` линией  указал, можно сказать, всю проблему: как заставить `article` иметь 100% ширину  помещенной в него картинки?
Лехчайшим образом можно взять из этой картинки все параметры через js и засунуть их в атрибуты блока `article`, но увы! Так делать нельзя, ведь если посмотрите в css, то там используются vh, ну и вообще, там много свойств, которые намекают вам, что всё должно легко ресайзится.
Имеется [codepen](http://codepen.io/VostokSisters/pen/BppdPo?editors=1100), если надо поиграться.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 153, 0.3);
}
.overlay article {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  max-height: 70vh;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  outline: 1px dotted green;
}
.overlay article img {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 100%;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="overlay">
  <article>
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/300/400" />
  </article>
</div>
```

Comment: Вам нужно, что бы article имел полную ширину картинки? А высоту?

Comment: Yuri, так а с высотой-то нет проблем. Высота автоматичесеки высчитывается, а вот ширина этим не хвастается) Есть хак на `inline-block`, но он не работает с абсолютным позиционированием по всей видимости.
Ну а высота ограничивается `max-height: 70%`, но это дизайнерская фича и к вопросу не имеет никакого отношения.

Comment: Я не понял, вам нужно, что бы article настоящую ширину картинки? Тогда зачем вы добавили к ней `position: absolute`?

Comment: @Yuri, мне не нужно чтобы артикл имел ширину такую, которая на данный момент отображается с учетом ограничения высоты по вьюпорту (70%, смотрите в свойстве). То есть либо настоящую ширину картинки, либо с этим ограничением. Короче: прям те параметры, которые у картинки и есть в отображении.
А позишн абсолют (у картинки) тут ни к чему, это так - поиски решений, забыл убрать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 153, 0.3);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.overlay article {
  outline: 1px dotted green;
}

.overlay article img {
  display: block;
  max-height: 70vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="overlay">
  <article>
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/1400/1500" />
  </article>
</div>
```

Comment: Вот черт, полностью удовлетворяет всему это решение :D Опять о таком не подумал, потому что после работы с анимацией абсолютно позиционированных элементов прям поклялся себе, что не буду больше flex юзать. В фаерфоксе глючит. А работает как надо: в предыдущем примере, например, если ширина становилась меньше картинки, элемент совсем исчезал, в моем примере картинка уходила вправо, а с флексами всё прекрасно - по центру контейнер остается. Красота. Если бы ещё анимация не лагала и [позиционирование](https://vk.cc/676l5v)  в фаерфоксе, то было бы круто. Спасибо за ещё одно решение)

Answer (score 3):

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 153, 0.3);
  text-align: center;
}

.overlay::before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.overlay article {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  outline: 1px dotted green;
}

.overlay article img {
  display: block;
  max-height: 70vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="overlay"><!-- No spaces --><article>
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/1400/1500" />
</article></div>
```

Comment: Точно, хорошее решение, я совсем забыл про хак с псевдоэлементом)
Спасибо! Вполне себе решение и ответ на вопрос.
Ток вот не очень люблю этот прием, прям как отрицательные марджини, а уже ведь 2017-й год на дворе... Неужели прям вообще никак больше?

Comment: Можно всё. См. другой ответ.

Answer (score 1):

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 153, 0.3);
}

.overlay article {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  max-height: 70vh;
  width: -webkit-min-content;
  width: -moz-min-content;
  width: min-content; /* IE лесом */
  outline: 1px dotted green;
}

.overlay article img {
  display: block;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="overlay">
  <article>
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/1400/1500" />
  </article>
</div>
```

Comment: А вот такого: `width: min-content`,  я совсем не встречал)
Погуглил - на css-tricks рассказывают, правда [поддержка](http://caniuse.com/#search=min-content) хромает. Но вроде клево! Наверно, его и включу. А поддержку допилят, думаю, быстро, свойство гениальное. Но а флексы глючат как по мне) Спасибо.

Comment: Префиксы покрывают всё, кроме Оперы 12 и IE/Edge. Флексы не глючат. Ответ с флексами лучше.

Comment: Ну вот например, очень легкий [пример](https://vostoksisters.github.io/), тут меню и то умудряется подглючивать.  А ведь там всего лишь транзишн по флекс-гров и пара других анимаций через туггл классов.
Ну наверно флексы не так уж и страшны, конечно. Просто если их использовать для статики, как раз для такого рода задачи, то да, это идеальное решение. Но если работать с анимацией, я всё же думаю, что флексы заставляют браузер отрисовывать ненужные моменты и из-за этого начинает всё лагать.

Comment: @VostokSisters, глючит только если какую-нибудь жесть написать, [типа такого](//stackoverflow.com/q/40138864/4928642). А вообще, не глючит.

Comment: Тогда такой вопрос не по теме: а почему флексами мало кто пользуется из сайтов, которые рассчитаны на большое количество аудитории? Все сайты, типа вк, инстаграмм, фейсбук, ютюб, все сделаны из супов из дивов с солянкой из классов, а не из использования новомодных свойств? Дело же в производительности?

Comment: @VostokSisters, видел только один реальный случай, когда причиной тормозов был css и это был не flex. Просто, вероятно, эти сайты поддерживают больший набор браузеров, чем те, в которых есть flex. Ну либо их разработчики flex не умеют.

Comment: Хм.. А чего у меня этот сниппет в FF не работает?

Comment: А не знаю почему) Если проинспектировать, то ширина будет равна 1400 пикселей, хотя свойство выбранно как надо.  Но я добавлял на локалку этот способ, он работал в фаерфоксе как надо. Это странно. К слову, всё-таки рискнул и выбрал флексы как окончательный вариант для реализации)

Comment: @VostokSisters, ещё тот ответ прими вместо этого)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52056/discussion-between-vostoksisters-and-qwertiy).